# Spring read-only transaction committing data to the DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle11g

I'm trying to implement a `read-only` transaction for a service method, following item 11.5.2 of the [Spring Framework Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), but the transaction still automatically commits data to the DB.

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 3.5.5-Final and Oracle 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0. Here is my setup:

The XML for the advice, the pointcut, the advisor and the transaction manager:

```xml
<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="myServiceMethods" expression="execution(* my.example.service.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="myServiceMethods" advice-ref="transactionAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <!-- the sessionFactory bean declaration does not set the -->
    <!-- hibernate.connection.autocommit property as either true or false -->
</bean>
```

The service interface:

```
package my.example.service;

public interface MyService {

    void getFoo();

    void bar();
}
```

The service implementation:

```
package my.example.service.impl;

import my.example.dao.MyDao;
import my.example.domain.MyEntity;
import my.example.service.MyService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    public void getFoo() {
        MyEntity example = this.dao.getMyEntity(1L);
        example.setSomeInteger(2);
        example.setSomeString("three");
    }

    public void bar() {
        MyEntity example = this.dao.getMyEntity(4L);
        example.setSomeInteger(5);
        example.setSomeString("six");
    }
}
```

After calling either `getFoo()` or `bar()`, the DB is updated, even though `getFoo()` is marked as `read-only`. But if I change these two lines:

```
<tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
<tx:method name="*"/>
```

to:

```
<tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
```

both methods respect the `read-only` property and data does not get committed to the DB.

What's going on? What am I doing wrong? What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out why the `read-only` transactions were being overriden. There is an [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) declared in `web.xml`, which previous developers used to prevent `LazyInitializationException`s when loading the user and its roles in the controller/interface.

Here is the filter declaration:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

I worked around the issue by configuring the filter to let each transaction use its own session (called `deferred mode`).

Here is the filter declaration with `deferred mode` activated:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Please, read the NOTE in the filter's Javadoc. My DAO class extends `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport`, and the the Hibernate Session returned by the inherited methods `getSession()` or `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` had its flush mode is set to `FlushMode.MANUAL`, instead of `FlushMode.NEVER`, as I exptected after reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712328/952808).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the readOnly flag on the `@Transactional` annotation.

Annotate your method with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` and Hibernate will attempt to perform the transaction in a read-only manner and (I think, you may want to double check this) will throw an exception if a write is attempted.

There is no point in trying to re-invent the wheel, where this is concerned.

Comment: The actual application has 39 service classes with about 20 public methods each, that's why the previous developers chose the XML approach. Now, if I enable `<tx:annoation-driven/>` on the XML and add `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to and individual method, it get ignored/overridden by `<tx:method name="*"/>`. Data still gets committed.

Comment: Completely removing the transactional advices, pointcuts and advisors from the XML, adding `<tx:annoation-driven/>`, and annotating individual methods with `@Transactional` and `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` *does* work **if** `SessionFactory. getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(myEntityInstance)` is not called inside the `read-only` method. No `Exception` is thrown if `saveOrUpdate()` is calledd inside a `read-only` method.