# significance of @Transactional(read-only = true)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I was trying to understand an existing code and then I found the use of `@Transactional(read-only = true)` in the code.
I went through this link.([Spring @Transactional read-only propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation)).
But I cannot relate it to my case.

I am using Hibernate as the ORM tool and uses `HibernateTransactionManager` to manage the transactions.
As per my understanding, code is trying to commit some data to a set of tables and before that I need to fetch some data from two master tables.
If the master table query returns nothing, an exception should be thrown.
Following is the skeleton of the entire code.

```
@Transactional
persistSomeData(int id){

    MasterData masterData = getMasterData(id);

    if(null == masterData)throw new Exception("No Master data found !!");

    persistChildTableData(masterData.someField);

}

@Transactional(read-only = true)
MasterData getMasterData(int id){
    //query to get the masterdata using id
}
```

I want to know the significance of `read-only = true` in the `getMasterData()`.

Comment: `getMasterData` can be called from other places as well. It could be called from services which start read-only transactions. Thumb rule is you create transactions based on what your method wants to do, not based on why / from where it is called.

Comment: This is the only place where it is used. Did you mean that it has no impact on the parent method transaction? Could you please elaborate?