# @Transactional(readOnly = true) not working as expected by Spring framework Version 5.2

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions

From [Spring Framework Version 5.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#spring-orm) whenever a method is marked @Transactional(readOnly=true) I should be expecting:

- `Session.setDefaultReadOnly(true)`.
- flushMode is set to **MANUAL**/**NEVER** but not **COMMIT**( as per this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation)).

However when I am trying with readOnly=true both of the above conditions are not as it is expected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example");
        config.setDriverClassName(Driver.class.getName());

        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        config.setUsername("root");
        config.setPassword("root1234");



        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(11);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.hibernatedemo");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return txManager;
    }
}

     @Service
     public class PostService {
        .
        .
        .
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public List<Post> getByTitles(List<String> titles) {
            List<Post> posts = postDao.getByTitle(titles);
            System.out.println(entityManager.getFlushMode());
            Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
            System.out.println(session.isDefaultReadOnly());
            printLoadedState(posts);
            return posts;
        }
     }

     @Repository
     public class PostDao {
        .
        .
        .
        public List<Post> getByTitle(List<String> titles) {
           Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
           return session.createQuery("select p from Post p where title IN :titles", Post.class)
                .setParameter("titles", titles).getResultList();
        }
     }
```

Here are the logs:

```
[2019-11-25 18:37:30] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.getTransaction -  [  ] Creating new transaction with name [com.example.hibernatedemo.service.PostService.getByTitles]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
[2019-11-25 18:37:30] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction -  [  ] Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@676721780 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@66522ead] read-only
[2019-11-25 18:37:30] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.<init> -  [  ] On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
[2019-11-25 18:37:30] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.begin -  [  ] begin
.
.
.
flushMode: COMMIT
readOnly: false
.
.
.
[2019-11-25 18:37:33] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.processCommit -  [  ] Initiating transaction commit
[2019-11-25 18:37:33] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit -  [  ] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1945987926<open>)]
[2019-11-25 18:37:33] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl.commit -  [  ] committing
[2019-11-25 18:37:33] [http-nio-8091-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.resetConnectionAfterTransaction -  [  ] Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@676721780 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@66522ead]
```

pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please add comment if anymore information is needed. I may be missing out on a basic config or something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling getByTitles method from the same class?

Comment: @AhmetAmasyalı i have updated the question. But why does it matter in this case?

Comment: AhmetAmasyalı was probably thinking about "The default advice mode for processing @Transactional annotations is proxy, which allows for interception of calls through the proxy only. Local calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way." https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html

Comment: Have you tried annotation getByTitle with `@Transactional`?

Comment: @AlexB In this case even if both the methods are in the same class it doesn't matter  because once PostServiceProxy has been created and a transaction is started, it should considered readOnly at that moment.
Have you tried annotation getByTitle with @Transactional? I tried, it didn't work. as I said while starting the txn in Proxy my readOnly property should have been processed.

Comment: Does the code you have posted match what you are running, as I note you have `@Service` on PostDao when it should be `@Repository` if you were following the article. Have you also got a `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation?

Comment: How you're calling it does matter.  If a session is already open as read-write the transactional method won't attempt to "escalate" it to readOnly for just that query (in my experience...).  For the flushmode you should be looking at session..get*Hibernate*FlushMode()

Comment: @AlexB updated postDao, added Config class,

Comment: You're still not really posting a minimum working example. You're omitting a lot of code in between your configuration methods. If you're using Spring Boot, you should also be able to delete most of those methods and just have the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`. If you make sure your application conforms as close as possible to a generic boot application, it is easier to flush out any bugs.

Comment: @AlexB i have added my full config file. i had a lot of comment which i was removing in order to post a cleaner file to undertsand.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I look at the source codes one more time. It should work if `HibernateJpaDialect` is set explicitly to `JpaTransactionManager` (which you already did through setting `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`) and after this [fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21494) which is released at 5.1 RC1.

Is it possible that the `@Transactional` method that you test is somehow called by another `@Transactional` method of some bean and that outer `@Transactional` method is `read-only=false` ? Because the setting of outer `@Transactional` method will simply override the inner one. (Assume the inner one does not the set as `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`).

On the other hand , you can also try to change the `@Transactional` method that you test to `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` to see if `readOnly = true` can take effect.

Comment: Neither a transaction manager type, nor a hibernate version have to do with the issue here. The problem is with Spring itself, which, at least for Hibernate, doesn't provide the optimizations, which could be provided for readonly=true case. This article describes the issue in details: https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/

Comment: @ Exterminator13  Wrong, the problem in your quoted link is already solved and rolled into [HibernateTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21494#issuecomment-453473546).It can also be verified if you look at the [`HibernateTransactionManager` source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2d86f221ce9e4df99aec801ae226ed228f5b64ac/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager.java#L512)  So , it is related to the transaction manager type

Comment: As I remember, for Hibernate, JpaTransactionManager uses HibernateTransactionManager under the hood. Given that, I don't think, that a transaction manager is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Exterminator13 , "JpaTransactionManager uses HibernateTransactionManager under the hood" , another wrong statement from you . `JpaTransactionManager` never use `HibernateTransactionManager` , I kindly suggest you to refresh your memory by looking at the source code to find the truth first...

Comment: KenChan By switching to HibernateTransactionManager and LocalSessionFactoryBean my @Transactional is breaking with exception. (ava.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder). I guess, I need to explore native HIbernate beans working first. But i wonder why do we need to setup hibernate native beans when solution was simple, if I am doing session.setDefaultReadOnly(true) , I am able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @MohdWaseem I look at the source codes one more time and `JpaTransactionManager` should also work if `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` is set explicitly to the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` which you already do in your setup. Anyway , please see my updated answer.

Comment: I am not calling from another @Transactional method. I tried REQUIRES_NEW but didn't work. https://github.com/mwaseem-mnnit/hibernate-demo/tree/master/complete here is link to the repo. in PostController i have getByTitle function "post/get/title" if this helps.