# Spring JpaRepository not working with transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have the following interface:

```java
public interface SnapshotRepository extends JpaRepository<Snapshot, Integer>, ISnapshotRepositoryExtra { }
```

that as you can see extends:

```
public interface ISnapshotRepositoryExtra {
    Optional<Snapshot> latest();
}
```

... I've implemented that `latest()` method in the following classes:

```
@Transactional
public class SnapshotRepositoryExtra implements ISnapshotRepositoryExtra {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Optional<Snapshot> latest() {
        return (Optional<Snapshot>) entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT r FROM snapshot r order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
                .getResultStream().findFirst();
    }
}
```

However when I launch the project, I see:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com...persistance.snapshot.ISnapshotRepositoryExtra.latest()! No property latest found for type Snapshot!
```

So my question is, why Spring does not see the class `SnapshotRepositoryExtra` that I've just made?

Comment: Because Spring tries to implement the interface by itself. Why not use an interface method with `@NativeQuery`?

Comment: @Turing85 and are there ways to tell Spring to take that class as implementation? (btw, is to have the Optional, but this is only a case where i can use `@Query`, but there are others where I can't)

Comment: Not that I know of. Spring tries to implement the method in a `JpaRepository` by itself, either by evaluating `@(Native)Query`-annotations or by [SpEL-conventitons](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). --- As far as I know, Spring Data JAP supports `Optional`.

Comment: I don't expect that `@Transactional` goes on the repository interface. Instead it should go on a service class.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I would advice against annotating the whole service-class with `@Transactional`. A better solution would be to annotate only methods that actually need transactional semantics, and configure the transaction properrly (e.g. by setting `readOnly = true` if applicable).

Comment: @Turing85 So in other words, there is no way to add "a custom method" to the JpaRepository interface?

Comment: As I said: there is. Add the method to the interface, annotate the method with `@Query`, set it as native query ([Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native))

Comment: @Turing85 well, thank you then, I'll try using `@Query`

Comment: @Turing85 - transactional is for multiple tables, so does it make sense on a single repository? It certainly doesn't belong on read method.

Comment: @K.Nicholas "*transactional is for multiple tables*" - Not really. `@Transactional` is for... well... transactional semantics. This means that either all operations encapsulated in a transaction pass or none of them. This can be (and often is) used on a single table. And it definitively belongs on read methods. That is what [`Transactional.readOnly`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--) is for.

Comment: Yea, not really. Try giving some useful information if you're going to bother. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614139/spring-transactional-read-only-propagation

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data is picky about how you name things.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) :

> The most important part of the class name that corresponds to the fragment interface is the Impl postfix.

In other words, you need to call your interface something like `SnapshotRepositoryExtra` and the implementation `SnapshotRepositoryExtraImpl` for Spring Data to recognise it (most examples I've seen would use something like `CustomSnapshotRepository` for the interface, but I don't think that convention is required).

That's for the latest version; previous versions of Spring Data had [different naming requirements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).

Comment: thank you so much, i'll certainly check this out, for the moment you got a +1 from me ahah